# Not able to initilize the JS view in openui5

Tags: sapui5

Not able to initilize the below JS view in index page. Could you please help me?
I m getting this error msg "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t.createContent is not a function"

Plunker link:
https://plnkr.co/edit/7v0CN93aDrAOY9WqU269?p=preview

app.view.js:

```
sap.ui.jsview("app",{

   getControllerName:function(){
       return "app";
   },

    createContent:function(oContoller){

       var oButton = new sap.m.Button(this.createId("helloButton"),{
          text:"Click Me"
       });

       return oButton;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the view code like this

```
sap.ui.jsview("view.js.app", {

    getControllerName: function() {
        return "view.js.app";
    },

    createContent: function(oContoller) {

        var oButton = new sap.m.Button(this.createId("helloButton"), {
            text: "Click Me"
        });

        return oButton;
    }
});
```

Also add a controller file app.controller.js and paste below code.

```
sap.ui.controller("view.js.app", {

    onInit: function() {

    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks. Any comments of view naming, i m not getting how the relative name and view name are working.

Comment: when i have the same code but in folder structure, my code is not working.

Comment: @niraj17 view.js.app means view/js/app.view.js.Ie it will look under view folder

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the **resourceroots** as **"view.js"** in the index file.

So while instantiating use below code

```
 var view = sap.ui.view({
     id:"idApp1", 
     type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS, 
     viewName:"view.js.app"
 });
```

And in the **view** add these changes,

```
sap.ui.jsview("view.js.app",{
   getControllerName:function(){
       return "view.js.app";
   },
   createContent:function(oContoller){
       var oButton = new sap.m.Button(this.createId("helloButton"),{
          text:"Click Me"
       });
       return oButton;
   }
});
```

And add one **controller** file named **app** as below,

```
sap.ui.define(["sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"], 
    function (Controller) {
    "use strict";
    return Controller.extend("view.js.app", {
    });
});
```

Here is the [working link.](https://plnkr.co/edit/U3jyRXViQpzH5ZiY980q?p=preview)